# Jquery file upload plugin

Tags: php, json

I am having issues with JSON parse while I am using the plugin in with file the error:

[image: json parse]

Comment: Which plugin? What is in the file?

Answer (score 0):

This means that your server response is not a JSON.

You may check the dev tools of the browser you're using. Network tab, check the reponse of the upload request.